# Automate adding users into AD group if not found

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set up a PS script to add members if they are not part of a group and run it as a task. Can someone proof the code and provide feedback? Thanks.

```
$GROUP = 'CN=Group1,OU=SomeOU,DC=domain,DC=local'

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=domain,DC=local" -Properties MemberOf | 
Where-Object {$_.MemberOf -notcontains $GROUP } | 
ForEach-Object { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $GROUP -Members $_ }
```

Comment: Group should be an array : $GROUP = @('CN=Group1','OU=SomeOU','DC=domain,'DC=local')

Comment: @jdweng what are you talking about? that's a DistinguishedName....

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon : It is an array of four objects,

Comment: @jdweng, no, it isn't. A [distinguished name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ldap/distinguished-names) is a _single string_ that just so happens to be composed of multiple pieces of information internally.

Comment: @mklement0 : The string is not one object, it is four objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code looks good but could be more efficient by leveraging the [Active Directory Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)):

```bash
$group = 'CN=Group1,OU=SomeOU,DC=domain,DC=local'
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!memberof=$group)" -SearchBase "DC=domain,DC=local" |
    Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $group
```

`-LDAPFilter "(!memberof=$group)"` searches all users not being a member of your group which is by far more efficient than querying all users in your Search Base and then filtering with [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell).

Comment: How would I exclude specific OU's from the -SearchBase? -notlike?

Would I bring back the Where-Object?

Comment: you could use `Where-Object` in that case (where `$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*$ou"` for example) Or you could loop over all OUs you want to target and pass each of them to `-SearchBase`. If that doesn't help please ask a new question with more details

Comment: Like this?
`Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*$ou" }`

Comment: @a3kop yup, but that should only work for 1 OU only! if you need to exclude more then you need to enumerate them

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` instead, which takes a user as the pipeline input and the group to add to as a parameter. Should perform a little better.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=domain,DC=local" -Properties MemberOf | 
Where-Object MemberOf -notcontains $GROUP | 
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $GROUP
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work without dumping every user (-ne won't do what you want and the filter doesn't take -notcontains).  -eq works with an array on the left.  -not has a high precedence, so parentheses are needed.

```
get-aduser -filter "-not (memberof -eq '$group')" -property memberof -SearchBase 'DC=domain,DC=local'
```